# Bevel isn't working on a vertex and I don't understand why

Tags: modeling

I have this vertex here:
[image]

When I press Ctrl + B, then V to bevel the vertices, it doesn't do anything in the preview and I don't know why:

[image]

Comment: That works fine here although I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve as the result isn't particularly nice! Please share your file so that we can see what's going on. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Seems like double faces / duplicate vertices

Comment: @JohnEason I'm just trying to flatten that vertex to simulate some wear and tear! I've uploaded the file here:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=r9ALl4yV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/r9ALl4yV/)

It's the object labelled pillar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, and bevel again.

Comment: This fixed the problem, I had no idea thanks so much.

Comment: I suspect that you'd duplicated the whole object without realizing it in Edit mode. If you had selected everything with 'A', you'd have seen weird shading called z-fighting because you had overlapping faces on the entire object. Merging by Distance removed 76 verts which you can see in the bottom status bar.

Comment: Thanks @JohnEason I think it must have been that!